# Sublime select a word shorcut with all signs

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

There is a shortcut
Ctrl + D    Select word - Repeat select others occurrences

but in the case of

'11.20'
or 
'SELECT#ME'

the shortcut will only select ether first "SELECT" or the second part "ME"

Is there a way to create a shortcut to select a whole word and only break it by ether single or double quotes or a space
so in my example it will select '11.20' and 'SELECT#ME'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set which characters are considered word separators by editing the `word_separators` setting in your User Preferences. The default value is:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Add the entire thing to your preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`** on Windows/Linux or **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings-User`** on OS X), remove the characters you want to be included as part of words (`#` and `.`, in your case), save the file, and you should be all set. Please note that the `\` characters in front of the `\` and `"` items are escaping them, so if you want to remove `\`, for example, you'll need to remove both back slashes.